# In what context are these mathematical symbols used?

Tags: notation

I just noticed that the Unicode character set contains an entire block (256 characters) of math symbols. I've got no idea how some of them should be used. For example:

- U+22DA (⋚) and U+22DB (⋛): less-than-equal-to-or-greater-than, and greater-than-equal-to-or-less-than. Why not just use the good old equals sign = ?
- U+2295 through U+2298 (⊕⊖⊗⊘): circled + − × ⁄ symbols
- U+2235 (∿): sine wave; why do we need a character for this? does anyone use this?
- U+2268 (≨): less-than-but-not-equal-to; isn't this redundant? if `x < y` then isn't it **always** true the `x ≠ y`?

I got these from [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=unicode+8704+to+8959) (you can click "more").

Thanks!

Comment: $\oplus$ is a special symbol, indicating "direct sum"; it is different from $+$. $\otimes$ is the tensor product, different from $\times$. Both are **extremely** common. The "sine wave" is not a sine wave, it's a symbol used to denote weak equivalence (often used for equivalence relations, or for stating that two functions are of the same order $\sim$.

Comment: The symbol $\lt$ is used for more than simple order symbols. For example, it is used to denote substructures (subspaces, subgroups). In those cases, you need a symbol that specifies that they are *proper* substructures, i.e., not equal to the original substructures. Again, the symbol is used quite a lot. I don't see your first two used much, but that doesn't mean they aren't, just like the fact that you don't see the others used somehow imply they are "useless".

Comment: Maybe you could use the first for something like: if $x ⋚ y$ then $-x ⋛ -y$ (similar to $\pm$ and $\mp$)

Comment: The "sine wave" is `U+223C`, not `U+2235`. If you click on the symbol on the page you linked to, you get a description of it, which among other things says "tilde operator".

Comment: @joriki: Actually it's `U+223F`— http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/223f/index.htm

Comment: "Some math symbols seem useless"... Yes, of course, most of them are when left unexplained and without context.

Comment: One book I have on group theory mentions an alternative name for ⊕ (and the like) — "hot cross plus", etc. This is highly appropriate, since the lot of them can then be referred to as bunnery operators. Badoom tish.

Comment: I'd rather have a plethora of unused math symbols than reuse symbols which could cause confusion, even with some context in its use. I can't think of any examples currently, but I'm sure there are at least a few out there. (Although this is more of a comment, I don't have the authority to make one.)

Comment: Wow, thanks so much everyone! I never knew most of this. I wish I could accept all the answers :) I'm giving it to Michael Hardy solely because he taught me the most, but everyone taught me something today.

Comment: ⊘ can be used for the measure of the diameter of a telscope

Comment: "- U+22DA (⋚) and U+22DB (⋛): less-than-equal-to-or-greater-than, and greater-than-equal-to-or-less-than. Why not just use the good old equals sign = ?"

Because that's not what the equals sign means. The equals sign means it has to be exactly equal, and cannot be greater than or less than. I think you mean to ask why anyone would use the symbol at all since the symbol seemingly could apply to any two numbers.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Heh, you're right, of course. (I now imagine that the intended use is within the context of non-total orderings—so while it can apply to any two *numbers*, we can partially compare other things than those!) Thanks for your correction, but I've left the post as is to preserve the context.

Comment: The sine wave ∿ (U+223F: SINE WAVE) IS the Unicode sine wave symbol. You are talking about ∼ (U+223C: TILDE OPERATOR). In general, it is important not to confuse similar-looking Unicode characters. For instance, – (U+2013: EN DASH) and − (U+2212: MINUS SIGN) are different, as are ° (U+00B0: DEGREE SIGN) and º (U+00BA: MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR), and β (U+03B2: GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA) and ß (U+00DF: LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S).

Comment: Ah, I realise now that the OP has made a mistake. The sine wave ∿ is U+223F, but the OP wrote U+2235 which is ∵ (U+2235: BECAUSE).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your "sine wave symbol" looks to me very similar to $\sim$.  Certainly that is used:
$$
X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)
$$
$X$ is a normally distributed random variable with expectation $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
$$
X\sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,p)
$$
$X$ is a binomially distributed random variable with parameters $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p\in[0,1]$.

$$
f(x) \sim \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{inx}
$$
The Fourier series of $f(x)$ is that series.  There is no commitment to saying the series converges to $f(x)$ (in some cases it does; in others it doesn't, and it can depend on which kind of convergence is being considered).

$$
a \sim b
$$
$a$ is related to $b$ (just which sort of "relation" is referred to depends on the context).

Comment: No, ∿ (U+223F: SINE WAVE) is not a mathematical operator. It is a symbol for a sine wave, defined by the Unicode standard. You are talking about ∼ (U+223C: TILDE OPERATOR).

Comment: In general, it is important not to confuse similar-looking Unicode characters. For instance, – (U+2013: EN DASH) and − (U+2212: MINUS SIGN) are different, as are ° (U+00B0: DEGREE SIGN) and º (U+00BA: MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR), and β (U+03B2: GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA) and ß (U+00DF: LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S).

Comment: Ah, I realise now that the OP has made a mistake. The sine wave ∿ is U+223F, but the OP wrote U+2235 which is ∵ (U+2235: BECAUSE).

Answer (score 13):

$\oplus$ and $\otimes$ are used to denote [direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum) and [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product), which are ubiquitous in mathematics. They also have a pedagogical use as symbols for addition in an abstract abelian [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) resp. multiplication in an abstract group when you want to make the point that groups are much more general than addition and multiplication of real or complex numbers. $\ominus$ is occasionally used in this abstract way as well.

Answer (score 11):

If $A \subset B$ are linear subspaces of a Hilbert space, $B \ominus A = \{x \in B: (x,y) = 0 \text{ for all }y \in A\}$.  $\ominus$ is also used for the symmetric difference of sets.

Answer (score 11):

$⋚$ and $⋛$ seem appropriate for use with partial orderings; i.e. $a⋚b$ would mean that $a$ and $b$ are comparable ($a⊥b$ is another convention for symbolising comparability).

Answer (score 9):

The sine wave symbol can be used when typesetting circuit diagrams to indicate that it's an AC circuit.

$\lneqq$ exists (at least if for no other reason) for completion's sake and/or symmetry with $\subsetneqq$ and friends.

Answer (score 6):

$\otimes$ is also used to denote the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of two matrices.

Sometimes, in analyses of floating-point arithmetic (like [this one](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/103162.103163)), $\oplus,\ominus,\otimes,$ and $\oslash$ are used instead of $+,-,\times,$ and $/$ to indicate the *inexact* arithmetic (i.e. with rounding) is being performed on numbers, instead of the ideal operations.

---

$\sim$ is also used in the representation of asymptotic expressions, e.g. [Stirling's formula here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E3). In there, it means that even though the series given is in fact divergent, truncations of it become a better approximation of the gamma (factorial) function as the argument becomes large.